# Problem with runnig NUnit tests under STA

Tags: c#, configuration, nunit

I have some NUnit test cases which need to be ran under STA model.

As discussed in many web sites or blogs (for example [here](http://blog.whconsult.com/CommentView,guid,20c8c370-3b07-49c0-89df-1c0e403b43cf.aspx)), I added a configuration file ("app.conig") to my NUnit test assembly with the following contents.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
       <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
     </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   <NUnit>
     <TestRunner>
       <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
     </TestRunner>
   </NUnit>
 </configuration>
```

To verify if a test is really ran under STA I put this test case:

```
 [Test]
 public void CheckSTA()
 {
    ApartmentState aptState = Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState();

    Assert.IsTrue(aptState == ApartmentState.STA);
 }
```

This works fine if I run my unit test on NUnit console or on NUnit GUI ***without using a NUnit project file.***

However, once I load the unit test to NUnit GUI through an NUnit project file (.nunit), the unit test starts to fail.

I've tried different config file name by following what's written on this blog ([Here](http://nunit.com/blogs/?p=9)), but using any config file name other than "app.config" causes my unit test to fail under any circumstance.

That said, what's the right way to set this up so that my unit test is ran under STA no matter what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with NUnit 2.5, you can use the RequiresSTAAttribute.

Comment: Please find documentation and sample code at http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5

Comment: The easiest 2.5 way is just to add the [assembly:RequiresSTA] attribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs. As you did, I found that NUnit projects were ignoring the App.config STA settings (although Resharper and Visual Studio would honour it). Applying the assembly attribute is a good fire-and-forget solution!

Comment: Bonus points if you update the answer to include NUnit 3.0's [`[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Apartment-Attribute]).

Answer (score 1):

Comments are often overlooked and because [jnm2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521757/jnm2) gave an important hint... and obviously I can earn some bonus points if add this comment as additional answer here... ;-)

For **NUnit 3.x** use [[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Apartment-Attribute)

*p.s. extra bonus: I fixed the link to the documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

For NUnit 3.11, another solution that worked for me is to put the following attribute in AssemblyInfo:

[assembly: RequiresThread(ApartmentState.STA)]